# Ionic build android failed with plugin error

Tags: cordova, ionic2

**I am running “Ionic build android” command and getting below error.**

cordova-android-support-gradle-release.after-prepare: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\Welfare_Research_2009\Development\EC\Main\LmpIonic\platforms\android\build.gradle

cordova-android-support-gradle-release.before-prepare: Wrote custom version
'27.+' to

C:\Welfare_Research_2009\Development\EC\Main\LmpIonic\platforms\android\cordova-android-support-gradle-release\properties.gradle

```
Discovered plugin “call-number” in config.xml. Adding it to the project

Failed to restore plugin “call-number” from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0

(node:20228) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0

My Ionic Info is as below
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1  
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2  
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1  
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0  
ios-deploy version: Not installed  
ios-sim version: Not installed  
OS: Windows 10  
Node Version: v6.10.0
```

I tried to remove the plugin from config.xml with no luck.

Any more ideas/suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with my Android build on Cordova.  The solution was to install a gradle plugin -- you might have the analogous for ionic.  The Cordova plugin was: `cordova-android-support-gradle-release`

Answer (score 1):

1. ionic cordova platforms remove android
2. ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
3. ionic cordova platforms add android

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to remove and re-add the plugin, doing it directly in the config.xml likely isn't the best way.  Try these:

```
ionic cordova plugin remove call-number
ionic cordova plugin add call-number
```

It's also not too uncommon to need to clear out other things occasionally with cordova build issues:

- Remove/re-add the platform in question
- Physically remove the plugins directory